# Error installing Crashlytics pod due to SSL certificate verfication

Tags: macos, curl, cocoapods, crashlytics

When I try to install the Crashlytics pod I get the following error:

```
Installing Crashlytics (3.7.2)

[!] Error installing Crashlytics
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/gd/z79q6q5s1xs6n9jp60hbc5_00000gn/T/d20160809-2596-11a0t7q/file.zip https://kit-downloads.fabric.io/cocoapods/crashlytics/3.7.2/crashlytics.zip --create-dirs --netrc

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (51) SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, of course. I also had a look on the related questions when I was writing this question. Though those had different error messages, which might be the reason I had no luck so far.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods-app/issues/355)?

Comment: Yeah. I've read this as well. I had the same problem with AFNetworking before. Then I found the workaround from your link, which solved the issue for AFNetworking. But as mentioned, this is a workaround not a real solution. I would like to understand the underlying issue and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Of course this workaround would be a quick fix, but I don't know which URL I have to provide for Crashlytics as it moved from github to cocoapod. Seems stupid I know.